# gsl_stats_skew returns wrong result

Tags: c, gsl, skew

I'm using GSL library 1.15 on a C application and I'm interested in computing the skewness of a data-set of doubles.
Theory :

[image]

which, according to matlab, should translate in :
[image]

It seems to me that the output of the gsl dedicated function **gsl_stats_skew** returns a wrong result.
Considering the following piece of code :

```
const double array[] = { 2.5, 3.7, 6.6, 9.1, 9.5, 10.7, 11.9, 21.5, 22.6, 25.2 };
const skewness = gsl_stats_skew(array, 1, 10);
printf("result : %f\n", skewness);
```

- the **expected** result is 0.5751
- the **returned** result is 0.41408

What am I missing?

Comment: I have a few general comments regarding your question. First, _always_ use the most recent version of the library that is 2.6 at the moment. Second, there is a variety of such numerical libraries and no standard implementation of pretty much any metric. I've checked numpy/scipy and their values of std/skew are different from what you get from GSL. Finally, your dataset is potentially too small to give you a stable result for this kind of distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that there are different ways to implement the skewness function, in particular :

- **biased** skewness : it's matlab's default and excel's SKEW.P function, which equals to 0.4850 on the previous dataset
- **unbiased** skewness : matlab computes it when you add flag=0, it's excel's SKEW function and it's the common way online calculators compute it => 0.57551
- **gsl** skewness : it's the biased version with a variation : the standard deviation is computed by using 1/(N-1) factor instead of 1/N => 0.41408

Here's my C implementation of the **biased** version, hope it helps :

```
double skewness(const double elements[], const int numElements){
  const double media = gsl_stats_mean(elements, 1, numElements);
  const double stDev = gsl_stats_sd_with_fixed_mean(elements, 1, numElements, media); // use 1/N normalization factor instead of 1/(N-1)
  double sum_numerator=0;
  for(int i=0; i<numElements; i++) sum_numerator += pow((elements[i] - media),3);
  const double numerator = sum_numerator / numElements;
  const double denominator = pow(stDev,3);
  return numerator / denominator; }
```